# OpenCv Face detection sample sometimes returns zero faces

Tags: android, opencv

I am using `opencv` for `face detection`. I am running `Open Cv FaceDetection` sample. The issue is

> Sometimes, Faces detection count returns zero even if there are faces in the
>   camera

Sample uses the following function on every camera frame:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
            int height = mGray.rows();
            if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
                mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
            }
            mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(mAbsoluteFaceSize);
        }

        MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

        if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR) {
            if (mJavaDetector != null)
                mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                        new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
        }
        else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
            if (mNativeDetector != null)
                mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces);
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
        }

        Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
        if(facesArray.length == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No face detected");

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Faces detected -> length : " + facesArray.length);
        }
        return mRgba;
    }
```

> Can anyone please let me know How Can I fix faces detection count
>   issue

Regards,